# Add to include path ( -I ) in Jamroot

Tags: bjam

I have a boost iostreams based project and executing
`export CPATH=/apps/bzip2/include/`
before `bjam link=static` works. Is there a way to set this in the Jamroot :

```
project infracore
        : requirements
          <include>$(PROJECT_ROOT)_install
          <include>$(BOOST_INCLUDE_BASE)
          <include>$(BZIP2_INCLUDE_BASE) #this does not work it seems
          <library>/boost/filesystem//boost_filesystem
          <library>/boost/system//boost_system
          <library>/boost/date_time//boost_date_time
          <library>/boost/iostreams//boost_iostreams
          <variant>debug:<inlining>off
          <variant>debug:<debug-symbols>on
          <variant>debug:<optimization>off
          <variant>debug:<warnings>on
          <variant>release:<warnings>on
          <library-path>/apps/bzip2/lib
          <library-path>/apps/zlib/lib
          <link>static
        ;

# Libraries
build-project UtilsCode ;
build-project ProfilerCode ;
build-project CommonDataStructuresCode ;
build-project Math ;

# Executibles
build-project fixfast ;
build-project Tools ;
build-project RiskConsole ; #u2ic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies the error was being reported from the boost installation. Adding  does work, except that it needed to be done in the boost Jamroot